# How to determine a permutation of $N$ integers with the maximal number of distinct adjacent gcds?

Tags: nt.number-theory, permutations

How to determine a permutation of $N$ integers with the maximal number of distinct adjacent gcds?

Given integers $p_1 , p_2 , p_3 , p_4 , p_5 , \ldots p_N$, which permutation of them will have the maximal number of distinct gcds when considering the adjacent elements? Note that we consider $p_N$ and $p_1$ to be adjacent.

Comment: When you write "maximum distinct values", what do you mean by "maximum"? How do you compare two sets of values?

Comment: it means how many disctinct gcds we get when we take gcds of adjacent elements

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for clarifying. I took the liberty to edit the title and to fix the LaTeX.

Comment: Do you have any results for small values of $N$ that you would like to share with us, just to give us a head start?

Comment: Are you still here, rbs?